# Docker sequence entries are not allowed here

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having problems with docker-compose.yml file.
This is error that is returning

> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: sequence entries are not allowed
>   here   in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 7, column 12

and this is my docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports: - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and it works.

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Comment: For reference, it’s **YAML** syntax, and for arrays/lists (called **sequences** in YAML), if you want to use the `-` style (as in `- "8000:8000"`), it has to be on separate lines.